# Segfault from calling strtok?

Tags: c

I'm calling strtok in my function in order to get two char *s from a comma delimited char *. It's segfaulting when I do and I'm not quite sure why.

```
Tree tree = create_node(NULL);
add(tree, "jacob");
add(tree, "jacob, blue");
```

(part of) the add method:

```
void add(Tree tree, char * input){
    printf("Add: %s\n", input);
    char * parent_name;
    char * child_name;
    if(strstr(input, ",") != NULL){
            const char delimiter[2] = ",";
            parent_name = strtok(input, delimiter);
            child_name = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }else{
            parent_name = input;
    }

    printf("pn, %s cn: %s\n", parent_name, child_name);
```

Actual results:

```
Add: jacob
pn, jacob cn: (null)
//Empty tree!
//jacob is the root
Add: jacob, blue
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It segfaults on the first strtok() call. I'm really stumped as to why. Sorry if this is really basic.

Comment: does `add(tree, strcpy("jacob, blue"));` work?

Comment: okay, that seems to be the issue, when i change input into a char[ ], it works. is there any way to refactor char *s into char[ ]s because this method is supposed to take in user input which comes in as char *

Comment: @Apto `char[]` and `char*` are functionally the same in this context. The operative part is `const`. A string literal is actually a `const char*`, but your function accepts a `char*`, no `const`. Honestly your compiler should warn about this.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Tree {
} Tree;

void add(Tree *tree, const char *str)
{
    char *input = strdup(str);
    char *parent_name = NULL;
    char *child_name = NULL;

    printf("Add: %s\n", input);
    if(strstr(input, ",") != NULL) {
        const char delimiter[2] = ",";
        parent_name = strtok(input, delimiter);
        child_name = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    } else {
        parent_name = input;
    }

    printf("pn, %s cn: %s\n", parent_name, child_name);
    free(input);
}

Tree *create_node()
{
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    Tree *tree = create_node(NULL);
    add(tree, "jacob");
    add(tree, "jacob, blue");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am still getting a segfault after trying this. it would be really great if i only had to do a little like apply a method to the input though

Comment: @Apto, @ccxshow only made a tiny change but couldn't be bothered to explain what it is. The change is that the input is now a `const char*`, and the first thing that happens is that the input is copied: `char *input = strdup(str);`. Of course it later must be `free(input);` or else you get a memory leak. I'd argue you only need to make the copy inside your `if` statement because if there are no commas in the string then you'll never call `strtok` and hence don't need to copy. I'd argue that the parent and child names should also be `const char*`, not `char*`. Always use `const` by default.

Comment: Your segfault comes because of that `free()`. This particular small example is correct because the values are only printed and never used again after the `free()`. I assume in your much larger code the parent and child names are actually used after this call to `add()`, and hence after the memory is freed.